# std::transform not working for statically allocated string

Tags: c++, std

Could someone help me understand why this doesn't work?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct person {
    int age;
    char name[30];
};

int main()
{
    vector<person> persons(2);
    vector<char*> names(2);
    
    persons[0].age = 1; 
    strcpy_s(persons[0].name, "mike");
    persons[1].age = 11; 
    strcpy_s(persons[1].name, "pol");
    transform(persons.begin(), persons.end(), names.begin(), 
        [](person p) -> char* {return p.name; });
    // ... names gets the same wrong pointer for both elements
}
```

[Edited to remove unnecessary wrong guesses]

Comment: This code does not compile. strcpy_s takes 3 arguments but 2 given.

Comment: The problem is not just `strcpy_s`. All modern C++ compilers are smart enough to tell you what the major bug in the shown code is. This is an example of never ignoring messages from your compiler. Even if it manages to compile the shown code, a warning messages is nearly always a guarantee that you have a bug. Pay attention to your compiler's warning message.

Comment: https://www.godbolt.org/z/WKoxd9

Comment: When you write C++ use C++ features and do not wite code like it would be a C code. In this case use `std::string`.

Comment: I'm not getting any warnings during compilation with MS Visual C++ 2019. Just tried GCC and... got the warning , good to know!
Also MSVC++ let me use strcpy_s with wrong parameters and no headers... not nice...

Comment: That's unfortunate. gcc gives a very understandable " warning: address of local variable ‘p’ returned", which is exactly what the problem is, as described in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this lambda:

```
[](person p) -> char* { return p.name; });
```

you are making a copy of each element in `persons`, and then returning a pointer to a member of the copy. This dangles as soon as you return from the lambda, invoking undefined behavior when you use the pointer later..

Instead, you could a return a pointer to a member of a reference:

```
[](person & p) -> char* { return p.name; });
       // ^
```

These pointers are valid so long as `persons` points to the same underlying memory. Modifying `persons` in a way that invalidates pointers to it will obviously invalidate the pointers in `names`.